# Merging two arrays

Tags: php

I have to arrays. Here is first:

```
array(3) 
{
  [0]=> string(10) "image1.jpg"
  [1]=> string(10) "image2.jpg"
  [2]=> string(10) "image3.jpg"
}
```

And second one:

```
array(3)
{
[0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) 
   { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["name"]=> string(6) "Name 1"
    ["file"]=> string(15) "f1335421531.zip"
    ["desc"]=> string(6) " "
   }
[1]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) 
   {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2"
    ["name"]=> string(6) "Name 2"
    ["file"]=> string(15) "f1335421552.zip"
    ["desc"]=> string(6) " "
   }
[2]=> object(stdClass)#24 (4)
   {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "3"
    ["name"]=> string(6) "Name 3"
    ["file"]=> string(15) "f1335421588.zip"
    ["desc"]=> string(6) " " 
   }
 }
```

How can I merge these arrays into one with following items:

```
[0]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) 
   { 
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
    ["name"]=> string(6) "Name 1"
    ["file"]=> string(15) "f1335421531.zip"
    ["desc"]=> string(6) " "
    ["img"]=> string(10) "image1.jpg"
   }
```

etc.

Is there any function to do it or maybe I need to write loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this:
$arr=array("image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg");
$obj= array((object)array("id"=>"1","name"=>"name1","file"=>"asdb1.zip","desc"=>" "),
            (object)array("id"=>"2","name"=>"name2","file"=>"asdb2.zip","desc"=>" "),
            (object)array("id"=>"3","name"=>"name3","file"=>"asdb3.zip","desc"=>" ")
  );
for($i=0;$i<count($obj);$i++){
    $newObj=(array)$obj[$i];
    $newObj['img']=$arr[$i];
    $newArr[]=(object)$newObj;  
}
echo "<pre>";var_dump($newArr);echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Thanks, your solutions works and fits exactly my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

First array, call it $images

Seconds array call it $objects

```
for($i=0; $i<count($objects); $i++){
    $object['img'] = $images[i];
}

var_dump($objects); //Check the result
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert each element of the second array into array type which is currently of object type and then iterating it using array_merge function you can achieve what you want.

Comment: The output example clearly states, that the result should be a `stdClass` with a new attribute `img`, not an `array`.

Comment: We can type cast it while iterating

Comment: We can, but we shouldn't do two conversions. It's a matter of overhead that you add to your process time (and memory), when the arrays are big enough.

Comment: As there is no in build function available for the solution we can. About memory: we can unset the variable after use. About processing time: we will have to compromise. Alternatively all the PHP functions are built in C language so we can create one for the use.

Comment: What? Just because there is no built in function for this, you have to do insane conversations back and forth? You have to create your own function which is effective, not by adding `2*O(n)` overhead to an `O(n)` simply assimilation. The goal is not always that, to get through a problem by a one-line code!

Comment: Alternatively all the PHP functions are built in C language so we can create one for the use... See my above comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific php function for this, so try the the following:

```
foreach ($array2 as $i => &$item) {
  $item->img = $array2[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$std1 = new stdClass ();
$std1->id = "1";
$std1->name = "Name 1";
$std1->file = "f1335421531.zip";
$std1->desc = "";

$std2 = new stdClass ();
$std2->id = "2";
$std2->name = "Name 2";
$std2->file = "f1335421552.zip";
$std2->desc = "";

$std3 = new stdClass ();
$std3->id = "3";
$std3->name = "Name 3";
$std3->file = "f1335421588.zip";
$std3->desc = "";

$obj = array (
        $std1,
        $std2,
        $std3 
);
$image = array (
        "image1.jpg",
        "image2.jpg",
        "image3.jpg" 
);

for($i = 0; $i < count ( $obj ); $i ++) {
    $obj [$i]->img = $image [$i];
}

var_dump ( $obj );
```

Output

```
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Name 1' (length=6)
      public 'file' => string 'f1335421531.zip' (length=15)
      public 'desc' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'img' => string 'image1.jpg' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => string '2' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Name 2' (length=6)
      public 'file' => string 'f1335421552.zip' (length=15)
      public 'desc' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'img' => string 'image2.jpg' (length=10)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[3]
      public 'id' => string '3' (length=1)
      public 'name' => string 'Name 3' (length=6)
      public 'file' => string 'f1335421588.zip' (length=15)
      public 'desc' => string '' (length=0)
      public 'img' => string 'image3.jpg' (length=10)
```